# "could not save history to file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/.psql_history": No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, psql, foreman

I am building a Rails project with Devise and Postgres.
When trying to migrate, I get this error message:

`PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "kala.wetzler"`.

I have tried this process a few times: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/ & after what seems like a success (no error messages) & I `\q` out, I get this message:

`could not save history to file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/.psql_history": No such file or directory`.

After this, if I try to migrate again I see that it does not recognize my password (as seen in the first error message listed in this post). Is it not working because of this lack of a file to save to or is that just telling me that this process of assigning a user to the database is not being logged? If it is because of a lack of the file to save to, how do I make sure that file gets created?

**My config/database.yml:**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost
  username: kala.wetzler
  password: <%= ENV['LIT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: lit_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: lit_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: lit_production
  username: kala.wetzler
  password: <%= ENV['LIT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

& then in my .env file I have LIT_DATABASE_PASSWORD assigned.

**My pg_hba.conf:**

```
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege.
local   replication     kala.wetzler                               trust
host    replication     kala.wetzler        127.0.0.1/32           trust
host    replication     kala.wetzler        ::1/128                trust
```

Comment: can you show us your database.yml file

Comment: Just added it to the post @Cyzanfar - along with the pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: Have you created the user and database already ?

Comment: Yeah, I just went in and tried to add myself to the database again with a different username, but same password & changed the username in the database.yml file but still got both of the same error msg's about not being able to save & then password authentication failing. But when I "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES" to myself, it replies with "GRANT". Then I `\q` out and it tells me it can't save it to psql_history file.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question: the user & database were definitely made before I granted privileges.

Comment: I feel like I should mention that I had zero postgres problems before I used foreman for the first time & left the server running while my mac was closed. I read somewhere that that can make postgres believe a port is being used, even when foreman is stopped.

Since then, I have uninstalled postgres & reinstalled it. I have tried building my project from scratch again but it doesn't matter. My password authentication always fails.

I wonder if it is a dotenv problem.. but if I leave my LIT_DATABASE_PASSWORD unassigned(in .env) - I get: `PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`